# mod_rewrite for specific domains in a mappings file

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mapping, rewritecond

I have a bunch of domains that I want to go to one domain but various parts of that domain.

```
# this is what I currently have
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*\.?foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ ${domainmappings:www.foo.com} [L,R=301]

# rewrite map file
www.foo.com www.domain.com/domain/foo.com.php
www.bar.com www.domain.com/domain/bar.com.php
www.baz.com www.domain.com/other/baz.php.foo
```

The problem is that I don't want to have to have each domain be part of the RewriteCond. I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but that will do it for EVERY domain. I only want the domains that are in the mappings file to redirect, and then continue on to other rewrites if it doesn't match any domains in the mappings file.

Answer (score 0):

You can  deref the map in a condition and make sure it's non-empty, and then capture it so you aren't going back to the map twice:

RewriteCond ${domainmappings:%{HTTP_HOST}) (.+)
RewriteRule .* %1 [L,R=301]